# Remove inline width from figure

Tags: posts, images, captions

I add an image with caption to my page and need to increase `<figure>` width. But wordpress is adding an inline width.

```
[caption id="attachment_44" align="alignnone" width="216"]<a href="image path"><img src="image path" alt="caption" width="216" height="95" class="size-full wp-image-44" /></a> caption [/caption]
```

So, the DOM look like this:

```
<figure id="attachment_43" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_43" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 216px">
   <a href="">
       <img src="http://localhost/bordados/website/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/homeThumb01.jpg" alt="Caption" width="216" height="95" class="size-full wp-image-43">
   </a>
   <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_43" class="wp-caption-text">Caption.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

I try to remove width="216" from code, but the caption desappear.

How I remove this inline style?

Comment: Please show the Code how you inserted the attachment.

Comment: @fischi I'm using page editor. See code above.

Comment: WordPress' default caption shortcode uses a `div` - you must be using a plugin or theme that outputs `figure` instead, which we need to know in order to help.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I'm using roots theme

Comment: The markup is controlled by the `img_caption_shortcode` filter, located in roots theme in `/lib/cleanup.php`. Search this site for `remove_filter` and `add_filter` to learn about overriding that in a child theme.

Comment: @Milo Thanks Milo. I commented the line 161 of file cleanup.php and solved my problem

Comment: @marcelo2605 Just a friendly reminder note that when you would like to modify a theme or plugin, it is the best and recommended if you could use filter/action hook to overcome. Because when you update the theme or plugin. Your manually edited code will be gone while you most likely will have it forgotten later. It could also increase the ease of maintenance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I'm using roots theme. So I open cleanup.php file and comment/remove this line:

```
$attributes .= ' style="width: ' . (esc_attr($attr['width']) + 10) . 'px"';
```

Comment: Glad you solved it! You can accept your own answer :) Also, I recommend editing your original post to state which theme you are using, so if anyone else comes across this it's easy for them to solve too. This question is only specific to this theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the width with a filter. Any falsy value will remove the attribute from the `<figure>`.

```
add_filter('img_caption_shortcode_width', '__return_false');
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be best practice, but you could select the css in a style sheet with

```
.wp-caption {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
```

this will override the in-line style.

Answer (score -2):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("figure").removeAttr("style");
});
```

Comment: Explanation as it how helps OP would be great!

Comment: This would remove any `style` attribute, also this would remove it in case JavaScript is enabled. Looking at the solution, I would assume this is not the OPs intention.